# Laravel getAttribute return undefined variable pushData

Tags: php, laravel

whats wrong with my code if i get all of my data it return undefined variable $pushData, but when i get it based on id(only 1 data) it can return for sure

```
public function getCategoryAttribute()
{
    $baseData   = Category::whereHas('products', function($query) {
        $query->where('product_id', $this->id);
    })->get();

    foreach($baseData as $baseData) {

        $pushData[] = [
            'name'          => $baseData['name'],
            'slug'          => $baseData['slug'],
            'description'   => $baseData['description'],
        ];

    }   
    return $pushData;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do with would be using `map`:

```
public function getCategoryAttribute()
{
    return Category::whereHas('products', function($query) {
        $query->where('product_id', $this->id);
    })->get()->map(function(Category $category) {
        return $category->only(['name', 'slug', 'description']);
    });
}
```

Comment: it return      Method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::map does not exist. so what happen?

Comment: Didn't need the `each` in there, only `->get()->map()`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for myself

just add `$pushData = [];` 
before foreach